# How to sum lists with identical character ID columns but different numeric values

Tags: r, purrr

Is there any way to do numerical calculations (add, mean, etc) on lists that contain tibbles of the same dimension and include a character ID vector?

Example:

```r
require(tidyverse)
#> Loading required package: tidyverse
x <- lst(a = tibble(id = letters, val = 1:26),
         b = tibble(id = letters, val = 27:52))

#This doesn't work of course
x %>% 
  reduce(`+`)
#> Error in FUN(left, right): non-numeric argument to binary operator

#This does, but we lose our identifiers
x %>% 
  map(~select(., -id)) %>% 
  reduce(`+`)
#>    val
#> 1   28
#> 2   30
#> 3   32
#> 4   34
#> 5   36
#> 6   38
#> 7   40
#> 8   42
#> 9   44
#> 10  46
#> 11  48
#> 12  50
#> 13  52
#> 14  54
#> 15  56
#> 16  58
#> 17  60
#> 18  62
#> 19  64
#> 20  66
#> 21  68
#> 22  70
#> 23  72
#> 24  74
#> 25  76
#> 26  78
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Update:

This kind of works, but it only takes the names of the first list item, which seems prone to the possibility of error:

```r
y <- lst(a = tibble(id = letters, val = 1:26),
         b = tibble(id = LETTERS, val = 27:52))


y %>% 
  map(~column_to_rownames(., "id")) %>% 
  reduce(`+`) %>% 
  rownames_to_column("id")
#>    id val
#> 1   a  28
#> 2   b  30
#> 3   c  32
#> 4   d  34
#> 5   e  36
#> 6   f  38
#> 7   g  40
#> 8   h  42
#> 9   i  44
#> 10  j  46
#> 11  k  48
#> 12  l  50
#> 13  m  52
#> 14  n  54
#> 15  o  56
#> 16  p  58
#> 17  q  60
#> 18  r  62
#> 19  s  64
#> 20  t  66
#> 21  u  68
#> 22  v  70
#> 23  w  72
#> 24  x  74
#> 25  y  76
#> 26  z  78
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

The solution to the worry about different IDs would be a join,  however then I am faced with how to specify the columns to add and this becomes a bigger problem when there are two or more original numeric columns:

```r
require(tidyverse)
#> Loading required package: tidyverse
z <- lst(a = tibble(id = letters, val = 1:26, otherval = 101:126),
         b = tibble(id = letters, val = 27:52, otherval = 127:152))
z %>% 
  reduce(left_join, by = "id")
#> # A tibble: 26 x 5
#>    id    val.x otherval.x val.y otherval.y
#>    <chr> <int>      <int> <int>      <int>
#>  1 a         1        101    27        127
#>  2 b         2        102    28        128
#>  3 c         3        103    29        129
#>  4 d         4        104    30        130
#>  5 e         5        105    31        131
#>  6 f         6        106    32        132
#>  7 g         7        107    33        133
#>  8 h         8        108    34        134
#>  9 i         9        109    35        135
#> 10 j        10        110    36        136
#> # … with 16 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Do you need `x %>% reduce(inner_join, by = 'id') %>% transmute(id, val = val.x + val.y)`. or may be `x %>% map(~ .x %>% select(val)) %>% reduce('+')`

Comment: Another option `bind_rows(x) %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(val = sum(val))`

Comment: @DarrenTsai No need to worry at all. Great minds ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bind_rows()` to merge data and group all observations according to `id`.

```
x %>% bind_rows %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(val = sum(val))

# A tibble: 26 x 2
   id      val
   <chr> <int>
 1 a        28
 2 b        30
 3 c        32
 4 d        34
 5 e        36
 6 f        38
 7 g        40
 8 h        42
 9 i        44
10 j        46
# ... with 16 more rows
```

Comment: I love feeling like an idiot on SO :).  Thanks Darren.